# Entity Framework: ASP.NET app with one dbContext per database

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am relatively new to Entity Framework.  I am learning it in my free time as none of the apps at work use it.  I am thinking about using it for new development.

My question surrounds the dbContext.  I have read questions like this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b017c5c-b270-4c77-83a7-f3b2b395a147/multiple-datacontext-classes?forum=adodotnetentityframework, which suggest that you have one context per database or many contexts per database (if you had a large database and wanted to split it into functional areas).

What happens if you have an app that connects to multiple databases.  I read somewhere earlier that you should only connect to one database per application.  Surely this isn't correct? If you have an app that connects and maintains information from twenty databases then could you have 20 spearate contexts (extreme example I know)?

Comment: You would probably require 20 data contexts in this case, as each context instances has connection details to a single DB.  However, that said, if this is your requirement, you would probably look at different ways of implementing this rather than 20 different connections (e.g. views on one DB referencing the others, synonyms etc.).

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of having one database connection and then creating linked servers to the 20 databases.  Is that what you meant by "views"? what do you mean by synonyms?

Comment: That would be what I meant by views.  Linked servers if your DBs are on different boxes I guess.  Easier to google synonyms for sql server to get the full idea here...

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it was just your terminology.  I have looked up synonyms here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx.